# SQL Server 2008 - what is the fastest way to see if rows from one table exist in another, with grouping?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the quickest way to locate all Projects in @Table2 that contain ALL rows in @Table1.  For example, given the following data the answer should only be Project ID = 1, as it contains ALL rows in @Table1.  Project 2 should be excluded as it does not contain Manchester.

```
declare @Table1 table (country varchar(50), city varchar(50))
insert into @Table1 (country, city) values ('United Kingdom', 'London');
insert into @Table1 (country, city) values ('United Kingdom', 'Birmingham');
insert into @Table1 (country, city) values ('United Kingdom', 'Manchester');


declare @Table2 table (projectid int, country varchar(50), city varchar(50))
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (1, 'United Kingdom', 'London');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (1, 'United Kingdom', 'Birmingham');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (1, 'United Kingdom', 'Manchester');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (1, 'United Kingdom', 'Liverpool');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (2, 'United Kingdom', 'London');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (2, 'United Kingdom', 'Birmingham');
insert into @Table2 (projectid, country, city) values (2, 'United Kingdom', 'Liverpool');

select * from @Table1
select * from @Table2
```

I've looked a little into EXCEPT ([this post was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353727/sql-server-check-if-all-rows-exists-in-other-table)) but can only get this working without using the Project ID.  Is there some clean SQL code that can help?  In my database I expect to have up to 100,000 rows.

Many thanks

Comment: so it is ok that table2 has row(s) that are not in table1? You have Liverpool in table 2 but it isn't in table 1.

Comment: Yes, it is okay that Table 2 has rows that are not in Table 1.  Your response works for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I think I understand the requirements to be this is one way to do this.

```
select t2.projectid
from @Table1 t1
join @Table2 t2 on t1.country = t2.country 
    and t1.city = t2.city
group by t2.projectid
having count(distinct t2.country + t2.city) = (select count(*) from @Table1)
```

Comment: Works for me!  Many thanks Sean for your prompt response.